# Programming error while saving json data to django model using amazon redshift

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Got the following error while inserting data into Django model. I am storing JSON data after converting data into a string in Amazon Redshift PostgreSQL

```
db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "RETURNING".
```

Comment: please add the code that is triggering the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error because id is my primary key and it is AutoField (created default by Django if we don't specify any primary key) and Amazon Redshift doesn't support it. Still working on it. Will update the answer once it is solved.